# At most N rows from each group

Tags: sql, ms-access, greatest-n-per-group

I have a SQL table containing customer information (we'll call it `CustomerDB`), including an address column.  Many of the rows in this table have exact duplicate addresses.  The business requirement is to retrieve rows from the database such that:

- If there are *more then three* exact duplicates, only take three (ignore the rest)
- Which three is not important; any three will do (it does not have to be the "first three").

So, if I have a data set like this (I have also [entered this in the Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/qe/2214/test-data-for-so-question), to make it easy to test queries against):

```
ID     NAME       COMPANY    ADDR1
16242  TOM E      Company A  101 First RD  
16241  RONALD J   Company B  12 Tenth AVE  
16235  KENNETH H             12 Tenth AVE  
16238  MICHAEL H  Company C  12 Tenth AVE  
16243  ANTONIO D  Company D  264 Long ST STE 5  
16237  MICHAEL B  Company E  264 Long ST STE 5  
16234  WALTER L   Company F  73 North RD  
16236  CARL O     Company G  73 North RD  
16239  MICHAEL S  Company H  73 North RD  
16240  MICHAEL I  Company I  73 North RD
```

I would like to get all of those rows except for one of the "`73 North RD`" records.  I hope I'm making some sense here.

My mind does not work very well in set-based operations, so I'm confused about how to do this.  **I would prefer a solution with an explanation of *why* it works.**  Since I'd like to be "taught how to fish", so to speak =)

Additional Information:

- `ID` is an int primary key (auto-incremented)
- All other columns are text.
- Sometimes I get these datasets as Access DBs, sometimes they are in SQL Server.  So, I'd prefer a solution that works in both (i.e. does not use `CROSS APPLY` or `CTE`'s)

Comment: This falls in the `[greatest-n-per-group]` category (tag). Look into the links, under the **Related** header, on the right.

Comment: @ypercube Awesome, I'm looking into those now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible solution could be

```
SELECT c1.id, c1.name, c1.company, c1.addr1
FROM CustomerDB c1 LEFT JOIN CustomerDB c2
    ON (c1.addr1 = c2.addr1 and c1.id >= c2.id)
GROUP BY c1.addr1, c1.id, c1.name, c1.company
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3​
```

The magic (nice definition you gave) is done by `GROUP BY ... HAVING ...` part.
Sure you know `WHERE` is used to filter data while selecting; well, `HAVING` is used in conjunction with `GROUP BY` to filter grouped data (so after grouping).
So I first group data (order is important) by address and then limit the count for each group to three.
Now let's talk about the inner part (you didn't ask this, but I thought it was good to provide you a complete example).
The `ON` part is used to tell the engine which fields are to be used to join tables; here I match tables on address and then I take records having an higher id (so, sorting ascending).

Comment: Wow, that looks like it works on my full data set over here!  I guess it's the inequality (`<=`) in that `LEFT JOIN` that's doing the magic.  Can you explain how that works (i.e., why it causes the duplicates to show)?  If not, that's alright.

Comment: @jadarnel27: if you can be patient, I'm using my mobile phone and network goes down. When I have a good link a provide a better explanation. Thanks

Comment: @jadarnel27: I wrote something I hope you'll find useful :)

Comment: That makse sense!  I think I have a better understanding of this now.  Thanks again =)